# How to make xampp local wordpress installation public?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP and WordPress along it. Created a database and installed the platform all along. Opened the needed ports (8080) so it's publicly accessible also before that. It works.

The problem is that the I can't reach `http://IPaddress/wordpress/wp-admin` from an outside computer.

I can reach `http://IPaddress:8080/xampp/`, but thats the only page it will allow me to open. For the rest I get timeouts, unreachable.

I'd appreciate if someone tells me how do I make the C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress folder accessible publicly just like the /xampp one. Do I need to set some special permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you next:

- You should move Wordpress folder to **htdocs**.
- Change apache port to **80**, not 8080.
- **Open 80 port** in your router to your host, example: *192.168.1.32*
- [Change wordpress folder permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-permissions-at-localhost#post-2203290).
- Try `http://IPADDRESS/`

Anyway your solution is also in google.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your reply. My wordpress folder is already in /htdocs. I opened port 8080 because I read that 80 is often occupied. Either way, the port is workign I have tested that. The problem is that I only have access to /xampp folder. When I type http://IP I get redirected to /xampp and it works. When I type /ip/wordpress and so on I get either timeout or an error.

Comment: Not a blank page. An "Unable to connect" when it is anything different than the IP or /xampp.